# Handling 3 Files using awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, gawk

Consider following files:

`file1`:

```
boo,8,1024
foo,7,2048
```

`file2`:

```
foo,0,24,154
noo,0,10,561
```

`file3`:

```
24,154,7,1024,0
```

What I need is to go to ***File1*** and check if `$2==7`; if true, take `$1`, `$2` and `$3` from ***File1***; now I have to compare if `$1` from ***File1*** equal to `$1` from ***File2***; if true, I have to take `$3` and `$4` from ***File2*** which not exist in ***File1***, then I have to go to ***File3*** and check if `$1` from ***File3*** is equal to `$3` from ***File2***, and `$2` from ***File3*** is equal to `$4` from ***File2***; if yes, then I have to check if `$2` from ***File1*** is equal to `$3` from ***File3***, then if this condition is true, I have to compare `$3` from ***File1*** with `$4` from ***File3***, if `$3` from ***File1*** is more than `$4` from ***File3***.

I tried the following script:

```
cat [file1] [file2] [file3] | 
awk -F, 
'{if(NF==3)
    {if($2==7){a[$1]=$1; b[$1]=$2; c[$1]=$3}
    }else
        {if(NF==4){if(a[$1]==$1){d[$3]=$3; e[$4]=$4}
                  }else
                        {if(NF==5){if(d[$1]==$1 && e[$2]==$2){print a[$1], b[$1], c[$1], d[$1]}}
                        }
                  }

  }'
```

The desired output is:

```
foo,7,2048,24,154,1024
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That worked for me:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==1{++f} \
  f==1 && $2==7 {a1[$1]++; a2[$2]=$3; o=$0} \
  f==2 && a1[$1] {o=o","$3","$4; a3[$3]=$4} \
  f==3 && a3[$1] && $2==a3[$1] && a2[$3] && $4<a2[$3] {print o}' \
file1 file2 file3
```

**Explanation**:

- The first line (`FNR==1{++f}`) increments the file index to later determine in which file we are 1-3.
- **file1:** if `$2` equals `7`

  - fill an array `a1` with `$1` as index and `a2` with `$2` as index and `$3` as value
  - write down the `o` variable (output) with the first 3 fields
- **file2:** if `$1` of `file2` equals `$1` of `file1` (prevously written in `a1`)

  - append `$3` and `$4` to the output variable `o`.
  - fill an array `a3` with `$3` as index and `$4` as value.
- **file3:** if:

  - `$1` equals file2s `$3` (index of `a3`)
  - `$2` equals file2s `$4` (value of `a3`)
  - `$3` equals file1s `$2` (index of `a2`)
  - `$4` is lower than file1s `$3` (value of `a2`)
- **then:**

  - print the value of `o`.

Comment: Is there a need for backslash (apart the last) ? how about BEGINFILE (instead of FNR==1 ) ?

Comment: @Archemar BEGINFILE and ENDFILE are gawk extensions and the backslashes can all be removed, I inseted them, for better readablility: you can write that whole thing in one single line, but it would not look nice

Comment: @chaos, thank you, but unfortunately it always returns null.

Comment: @Azizieh7 I tested it with mawk and gawk with your 3 input example files. For me it worked. Do you use different input files or encodings/linebreaks?

Comment: @chaos, there is different linebreaks in file3, but I use tr -d '\015' to overcome this.

Comment: @Azizieh7 There must be simethign else, have you tried with your given example files? Without special encoding? I think there is something wrong with this file3.

Comment: @chaos `o` in your code will save the last record in `file1` only

Comment: @Azizieh7 `o` contains the whole line of file1 `o=$0` and later the field 3 and 4 of file2 `o=o","$3","$4`. I'm sure, your files have special encodings, can you upload the 3 demo files and give a link, so I can try with *your* files? What os are you working on?

Answer (score 1):

TXR solution:

```
@(repeat)
@id,@val0,@val1
@  (next)
@  (skip)
@id,@nil,@val2,@val3
@  (next)
@val2,@val3,@val0,@val4,@val5
@  (require (< (int-str val4) (int-str val1)))
@  (output)
@id,@val0,@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4
@  (end)
@(end)
```

Run:

```
$ txr join.txr file1 file2 file3
foo,7,2048,24,154,1024
```

But the astute observer will note that the 7 hasn't been specified anywhere in the code, appearing just in the output! That is because code is actually marching through all records in `file1` and **prints all the combinations that meet the matches and constraint**. The only one in the sample data is the one with `val0` being `7`.

If there were more combinations found, it could be constrained to just the `7` one like this:

```
$ txr -Dval0=7 join.txr file1 file2 file3
foo,7,2048,24,154,1024

# how about 6?
$ txr -Dval0=6 join.txr file1 file2 file3
# no output
```

The TXR pattern extraction language provides here one big pattern match with implicit back-references through the repetition of variable names, spanning multiple files, with multi-line extraction patterns, and non-textual constraints, plus embedded side effects like output, and so on.

Accepted Awk solution carefully translated the TXR Lisp [`awk` macro](http://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-000264BC):

```
(awk (:begin (set fs "," ofs ","))
     (:let o (a1 (hash :equal-based)) (a2 (hash)) (a3 (hash)))
     (t (mf [orf int-str identity])) ;; map those fields to integers, which can be
     ((and (= arg 1) (= [f 1] 7)) (inc [a1 [f 0] 0])
                                  (set [a2 [f 1]] [f 2])
                                  (set o rec))
     ((and (= arg 2) [a1 [f 0]]) (set o `@o,@[f 2],@[f 3]`)
                                 (set [a3 [f 2]] [f 3]))
     ((and (= arg 3)
           [a3 [f 0]]
           (= [f 1] [a3 [f 0]])
           [a2 [f 2]]
           (< [f 3] [a2 [f 2]])) (prn o)))
```

Run:

```
$ txr awkit.tl file1 file2 file3
foo,7,2048,24,154
```

The `,1024` required part in the output is missing; the original "Awk Classic" has this behavior.